# injecting service into actor gives NullPointerException

Tags: scala, web-services, guice, actor, playframework-2.5

I'm not able to figure out how to inject a Service into an Actor.

I tried out several approaches and think this one should fit best.

I think the major problem is that I provide the websocket to the succeeding actor as an parameter. When I pull the Inject up to the class signature compilation doesn't perform because of signature conflict.
I tried adding a currying implicit class declaration to inject the service, but this didn't work out either.

What shall I do to get it right?

Running this code results in a NullPointerException.

```
package actors

import akka.actor._
import com.google.inject.Inject
import play.api.libs.json._
import models._
import services.WeatherService

/**
  * Created by jbc on 28.12.16.
  */
class WeatherWSActor (out: ActorRef) extends Actor {

  @Inject() val weatherService: WeatherService = null

  def handleMessage(msg: JsValue): JsValue = {

    val req = msg.as[Request]

    req match {
      case Request("daily") => Json.toJson(weatherService.getFourDays())
      case Request("next") => Json.toJson(weatherService.getNextHour())
    }
  }

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case msg: JsValue => out ! handleMessage(msg)
    case _ => out ! "Bad Request"
  }

  @scala.throws[Exception](classOf[Exception])
  override def postStop(): Unit = {

  }
}

object WeatherWSActor {
  def props(out: ActorRef) = Props(new WeatherWSActor(out))
}
```

Controller Code:

```
class WeatherWSController @Inject() (implicit system: ActorSystem, materializer: Materializer) extends Controller {

  def socket = WebSocket.accept[JsValue, JsValue] { request =>
    ActorFlow.actorRef(out => WeatherWSActor.props(out));
  }

}
```

The service is set up with this Module Code

```
class Module extends AbstractModule {
    override def configure(): Unit = {
        bind(classOf[WeatherService]).to(classOf[WeatherServiceImpl]).asEagerSingleton()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the [documentation](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAkka#dependency-injecting-actors), but here's a summary.

If you want to inject your actors, you need to change a couple of things.  First off, the injection point is the constructor, so

```
class WeatherWSActor (out: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  @Inject() val weatherService: WeatherService = null
  // ...
}
```

should become

```
class WeatherWSActor @Inject() (out: ActorRef, 
                                weatherService: WeatherService) extends Actor {
  // ...
}
```

In fact, assigning `null` to a Scala `val` is also going to give you issues.

Secondly, declare a binding for the actor instead of creating it yourself.

```
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule
import play.api.libs.concurrent.AkkaGuiceSupport

import actors.WeatherWSActor

class MyModule extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport {
  def configure = {
    bindActor[WeatherWSActor]("weather-actor")
  }
}
```

On a side note, you'll also need to create a named binding for `out` and change the definition of `WeatherWSActor` to reflect this:

```
class WeatherWSActor @Inject() (@javax.inject.Named("out-actor") out: ActorRef, 
                                weatherService: WeatherService) extends Actor {
  // ...
}
```

`out-actor` is whichever class you have set up in the module, e.g.

```
class MyModule extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport {
  def configure = {
    bindActor[WeatherWSActor]("weather-actor")
    bindActor[SomeOutActor]("out-actor")
  }
}
```

**But...**

Since you're getting `out` when a web socket is created, you're (presumably) going to have multiple `WeatherWSActor` instances.  This is going to effect how you handle the dependency injection, so it make more sense to not inject `outActor` (and hence not create a binding for it), but rather have a singleton `WeatherWSActor` that broadcasts to all instances of `OutActor` addressed at a certain point in the actor system.